# Spring STOMP Java client and server pub/sub topic

Tags: java, spring, stomp

I am looking for an example or code snippets on using Spring's STOMP topic pub/sub messaging, with both the **client and server in the same tomcat7 instance**.  **NOT OVER THE WEBSOCKET.**

We want to handle some operations asynchronously in our server side and so want to use STOMP as our **messaging protocol** in our tomcat7 instance. Everywhere I look I find samples for STOMP over websocket or integrating with other MOM's!!

Anyone know about a java sample for simple spring stomp pub/sub? Appreciate any pointers...Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Spring Websocket Portfolio](https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio) application. Yes, I know you said not over websocket, but the application has some [tests that use a STOMP client/server](https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio/tree/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/samples/portfolio/web/support) that might just be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have been looking at the [Spring Websocket Portfolio](https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio) and also the https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-messaging-stomp-websocket. Even the unit tests you suggested end up coupled with websockets. Any working sample would help greatly. I know the spring dev folks monitor these STOMP questions and no reponse from them is telling. We are planning on moving on with zeroMQ. Concerned STOMP is not meant to be usd as a standalone Q and might run into issues in the future.